# matplotlib GTK ImportError

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk, homebrew

I installed `matplotlib` with `brew install matplotlib --with-cairo --with-pygtk --with-python3`. Running `import matplotlib.pyplot` causes a GTK `ImportError`. The `ImportError` is slightly different for Python 2 and 3.

Python 2:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 16 2014, 05:18:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 98, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 28, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkcairo.py", line 12, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtk import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk.py", line 33, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_gdk import RendererGDK, FigureCanvasGDK
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-override/matplotlib/backends/backend_gdk.py", line 30, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends._backend_gdk import pixbuf_get_pixels_array
ImportError: No module named _backend_gdk
```

Python 3:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 16 2014, 05:21:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.51)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtkcairo.py", line 10, in <module>
    import gtk
ImportError: No module named 'gtk'
```

Comment: What does `from gi.repository import Gtk` give you when executed in a python console?

Comment: Python 2: "Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!", but it seems to load successfully.  Python 3: ImportError: No module named 'gi'.

Comment: what does `import gtk` give you?

Comment: Python 2: Works.  Python 3: ImportError.